# Adding a customised menu with icon in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

Just wondering how I can add customised menus on MS Access like below.

[image: MY MENU ON MS ACCESS]

Comment: This question is way too broad for here. I can refer you to [this support page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-the-ribbon-45e110b9-531c-46ed-ab3a-4e25bc9413de), though.

Comment: I use this tool for creating custom ribbons: http://www.ribboncreator.de/en/

Comment: Thanks @SergeyS. I have been trying to find a way to do this in the MS Access but the tool you mentioned is how this menu was added by. Thanks again.